# How do I implement a 'Today' button in CVCalendar?

Tags: swift

I have [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) working, it displays dots on relevant dates and updates the month and year when I swipe left and right.

How do I implement a button to jump to today's date? It's included in the screenshot demo so I know it can be done but it's not implemented in the demo project and I can't find the corresponding function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is:

```
public func toggleViewWithDate(_ date: Foundation.Date) {
```

in CVCalendarView

So for example adding this to the ViewController

```
@IBAction func todayButtonTapped(){
    let today = Date()
    calendarView.toggleViewWithDate(today)
}
```

would work (remembering to add the button in storyboard and connect 'touch Up Inside')